# How do I use php to filter values based on what they start with?

Tags: php

How do I use php to only accept values that begin with "09"? For example, only `value 1` and `value 3` should be accepted in this list:

```
 value 1 ="09888111222";
 value 2 ="02999111222";
 value 3 ="09999111111";
```

i done it...

```
$cno="09888111222";
$countc=strlen($cno);
$countc1=-$countc+2;
$rest = substr($cno, 0, $countc1); 
if($rest==07){
echo $rest;
}else{
echo "Value not starts with 07";
}
```

Comment: http://us.php.net/substr is your friend.

Comment: Hey, he is new here. Don't downvote, say what is wrong with the question!

Comment: what i was thinking get first 2 digit and then validate it.

Comment: beginners always punished here...:(

Comment: @FinDav see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: please don't down vote it, there are lots still needs to learn..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (substr($value, 0, 2) === '09') {
    // Do something here... your string in $value starts with "09"
}
```

http://php.net/substr